# Database Error: "Could not find stored procedure 'sp_insert"

Tags: c#, sql

When I run the code in order to submit data to my database. The connection string to the database is correct. I have tested it for my logins.

I get this error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'sp_insert'

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (IP); Persist Security Info = True; User ID = sa; Password = 1234");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insert", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", textBox4.Text);
con.Open();
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: How about explicitly defining a database/schema to use?

Comment: If procedure `sp_insert` is really exists - probably you need to explicitly specify database. Something like `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DatabaseName.schemaName.sp_insert", con);`

Comment: [Do not prefix your procedure names with "sp_"](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). This is reserved for system stored procedures. Using it yourself has the potential to break things in the future and has performance issues to boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the database `Initial Catalog=myDataBase` within your `ConnectionString`

Source: 
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: I have no Initial Catalog in my connection string.